# Visualization of Specular Reflection of Optical Coatings on transparent substrate

Tags: image-processing

I was trying to convert the spectrum of specular reflection of an optical coating to RGB values. However, the problem is that because most of the un-reflected light are simply transmitted through the underlying transparent substrate, the intensity of the specular reflection is very weak.

However, this is represented by a spectrum that show very low R% for the visible wavelength region. When I convert this spectrum to RGB, the color patch shows a very dark color/reflection (which I realized now it make sense, since the R% spectrum is basically showing a spectrum where very little light is reflected, ie, a dark color)

I have tried to first convert the patch to HSV and adjusting the saturation value, but the resultant color just doesn't add up, I was wondering if anyone have experienced the same situation before?

Edit:

Sorry I wasn't clear in my previous question. I am trying create a RGB color patch from a fresnel reflection of light reflected off an optical coating of a transparent substrate, below is a simple diagram of what I am trying to do:

[Reflection off optical coating of transparent substrate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wmrax.png)

From the diagram, you can see that the target R% spectrum will give a dark red RGB color patch, which would be correct if the substrate is opaque, i.e. the substrate reflect its color and absorb the rest of the wavelength.

However, as my substrate is transparent, most of the light (D65 light source) is passed through the substrate while the optical coating will reflect 7.7% of the incoming light (which should give a very light red color patch of another hue). This will give a very low intensity reflection as most of the light is transmitted away.

I calculated the CIE XYZ tristimulus values from the spectrum and converted them to sRGB, it works for transmission but it doesn't work for Fresnel reflection (as stated above). I was wondering if there are other formulas that are able to give an accurate color patch for such reflections? I tried using some image processing algorithm to do rendering of Fresnel reflection. they work to a certain extent, however, I need the formula/equations as I would like to included them a program I am writing to analyse the colorimetric data of measured spectrum from optical coatings.

Thanks,
Johan

Comment: Do you have the target spectrum that the coating produces for a given light source? Because that will define the spectrum that will be reflected and the ones that will pass through without much effect (like Red as per your observation). 
Also, please rephrase the question a little so that its clear what you want to ask for a solution because this cannot be an open query/question like reddit for eg.

Comment: Hi, I edited my question, sry for not being clear earlier. Bascially, I am treating the specular reflection as a Fresnel reflection. I am able to render it using image processing software. But I am actually looking for the equations or the mathematical formula that can convert it the correct RGB shade (Fresnel equation only works in providing the correct spectrum) as I want to include in a program I am writing to calculate the various colorimetric values of a spectrum. The target spectrum can be found in the link in my edited post.Thanks!